# English qwertz keyboard layout on windows 10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want to have a english keyboard layout, but with QWERTZ insted of QWERTY.
I tried going to Settings > Time & Language > Language > English (United States) > Add a keyboard, **but I can't find any keyboard layout with QWERTZ.**
[image: Available keyboard layouts]

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to switch

- Y -> Z
- Z -> Y

You could use Microsoft official tool called Keyboard Manager. In order to install in you will need to install a set of tools called [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) (Microsoft official tools). There is a few ways of installing it, one of them is through the Microsoft store.
[image: Microsoft store PowerToys]

After installing find in the the search bar and open it.

[image: Search bar]

Open the keyboard manager and just remap the keys like this:
[image]

**NOTE:** By default the PowerToys has all the tools enabled, so you might want to disable all of them if you just need the Keyboard manager, or you might find something useful :)

**NOTE 2:** There is also a tool called [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134), but I haven't played with it. Here is a question that talks more about it ([LINK](https://superuser.com/questions/1176714/change-z-and-y-on-an-english-keyboard-on-win-10-w-o-buying-software/1751420#1751420)).
[image: Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator]

Comment: The remapping works good for English, but now the keys got swapped in non-English QWERTZ layouts too. Can I set the swap to apply to English only?